# SelectCommand with web.config key variable

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Looking to select records from my DB in ASP.NET using `<SelectCommand>` with a var from the web.config.

Can't seem to find the proper syntax to work.

no code behind file or vb code in page, so trying to do in just asp.net page.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM ClassesTbl WHERE AppName = <%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings('AppName') %>"
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: not a valid SQL statement - need to add as a parameter I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually found a way to make it work:

added:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="getAppName" DefaultValue="<%$ AppSettings:AppName %>"/>
</SelectParameters>
```

and changed SelectCommand to:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM ClassesTbl WHERE AppName = @getAppName"
```